# Your database connection has been reset. Any pending transactions or session state has been lost

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have recently installed Oracle SQL developer (version: 22.2.1.234)and
whene trying  to open the model for the tabels I get this error
"Your database connection has been reset.  Any pending transactions or session state has been lost."
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnCio.png)

I treid to add instantclient_21_7 and get this error
" Testing testing native OCI library load ... Failed:
Error loading the native OCI library "

Comment: What version of Oracle Database are you working with when you get this message? By the way, this isn't a 'fatal' message, you can click Ok and generally continue working. Are you saying even after doing so, you're not able to create the Data Model?

Comment: oracle 12c....... after clicking ok I'm not  getting the full table only the name of the table with no columns or relationships betwen tables

Comment: 12.1 or 12.2? there's a big difference

Comment: it is  12.1.0.1.0